# Заполнить нулями без memset и ZeroMemory (C++)

Tags: c++, memory

Добрый вечер! Необходимо реализовать полностью без CRT.

```
{
    STARTUPINFO SI;
    ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
}
```

В данном коде, необходимо заполнить SI нулями. С CRT сделать это можно с помощью memset или ZeroMemory(которому тоже нужен memset). Мне эти два варианта не подходят, как можно сделать это без поддержки CRT?

Сработает ли, если я просто объявлю SI таким способом? Спасибо.

```
STARTUPINFO SI[sizeof(STARTUPINFO)]{0};
```

Comment: `[sizeof(STARTUPINFO)]` - а это еще откуда взялось?

Answer (score 4):

Так

```
STARTUPINFO SI[sizeof(STARTUPINFO)]{0};
```

вы пытаетесь объявить целый массив `STARTUPINFO`.

Объявите просто

```
STARTUPINFO SI{ 0 };
```

Только вот тот же VC++ 2015, если посмотреть ассемблерный код, все равно при таком обнулении вызывает `memset`. Просто невидимо для вас.

Comment: Если у меня в настройках проекта полный отказ CRT (/NO:DEFAULTLIB), а я объявлю таким способом SI, что из этого может последовать? @Harry

Comment: У меня, например, вызывает ошибку компоновки.

Comment: Вот по этому поводу: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945619/276994

Answer (score 4):

Со времен классического С в языке есть идиоматический Универсальный Нулевой Инициализатор `{ 0 }`, который может использоваться для инициализации нулем/нулями вообще чего угодно. В вашем случае

```
STARTUPINFO SI = { 0 };
```

В языке С++, в силу ряда С++ тонкостей, вариант `{ 0 }` не всегда применим, а его роль выполняет инициализатор `{}`

```
STARTUPINFO SI = {};
```

Разумеется, в С++ все это будет работать как нулевой инициализатор только если класс не определяет своих конструкторов.

Отдельно можно заметить, что синтаксис `{}` инициализирует объект-приемник *логическими* значениями `0`, внутреннее *физическое* представление которых не обязано состоять из набора нулевых битов. А `memset` и `ZeroMemeory` как раз таки наоборот, *физически* обнуляют память, забивая ее нулевыми битами. Так что в общем случае стоит подумать о том, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: А инициализируются ли padding-байты при `{}`-инициализации?

Comment: @VladD Формально - нет, не гарантируется.

Answer (score 2):

В современных версиях C++ (тестировал на VS 2017) можно ещё проще:

```
STARTUPINFO SI { };
```

Требуемый в некоторых старых компиляторах ноль больше не нужен.

Comment: Я практически уверен, что в старых версиях Visual Studio он таки требовался (не скажу про стандарт). Но сейчас, к сожалению, не могу проверить.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно использовать placement new:

```
new(&SI)char[sizeof(SI)]();
```

Comment: @Abyx, а как вы еще заполните нулями кусок памяти без `memset`?

Comment: @Abyx, и это, по вашему, не "троллейбус"?

Comment: @Abyx, хотя соглашусь, через `fill` нагляднее

Answer (score 0):

Всё же такой вариант имеет право на существование.
На примере заполнения структуры.

```
//for memset example by Dinton BQ
#include <conio.h>
//#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

struct goko {
char bytes[4];
};

void myMemSet(char* pointer,unsigned char byte,int size)//именно unsigned(беззнаковый) char это байт
{
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)*(pointer+i)=byte;//pointer[i]=byte
}

int main(){
struct goko k;
unsigned char j[]="\xFF\xBB\xAA";//\xFF \xBB \xAA \0 //байты которые скопируем в структуру
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(j);i++)k.bytes[i]=j[i];//копируем все 4 байта строки

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(struct goko);i++)//отображаем байты структуры
printf("%i)%i\n",i+1,((unsigned char*)&k)[i]);

myMemSet((char*)&k,'\xFF'/*или 255*/,sizeof(struct goko));
printf("______________________\n");

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(struct goko);i++)//отображаем байты структуры
printf("%i)%i\n",i+1,((unsigned char*)&k)[i]);

    printf("\nPress any key to continue\n");getch();//остановить консоль до нажатия любой клавишы
    return 0;
}
```